# Polylang: Custom post type archive doesn't show in both languages

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives, plugin-polylang

I am trying to create an archive page for a custom post type which is not translated. All posts in this post type need to be shown regardless of the language and the content doesn't need to be translated so I decided not to activate translations for this post type.

However now I've come across the problem that the archive page is only available in the default language. When I click the language switch it send me back to the home page and when I try to go to what the URL should be I get a 404 response.

Is there any way I could get this archive page in all languages without needing to activate translation for this post type?

Thanks